# Test if a server is reachable from host and has port open with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to test if the host I am provisioning can reach a specific server and connect to a specific TCP port. If it can't the playbook should fail.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is [wait_for](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html) module for this.
To check that `target.host` can access `remote.host:8080`:

```
- hosts: target.host
  tasks:
    - wait_for: host=remote.host port=8080 timeout=1
    - debug: msg=ok
```

There are a lot of other examples in the documentation.

Comment: What will be the script if I want to run this against a group of servers from localhost ( where ansible installed)

Comment: @Techiescorner You possibly want the ping module. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ping_module.html It checks reachability of a target, as opposed to reachability of something from a target.

Answer (score 3):

Using `wait_for` is fine, however it requires the service is actually running and gives a reply.

If you just like to check whether the port is open in your firewall, you can use `curl`.

```
- name: Check if host is reachable
  shell:
    cmd: "/usr/bin/curl --connect-timeout 10 --silent --show-error remote.host:8080"
    warn: no
    executable: /bin/bash 
  register: res
  failed_when: res.rc in [28] or res.stderr is search("No route to host")
```

When the port is open but service does not run you get an `curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.192.147.224:27019; Connection refused"` which you would consider as OK.

A connection blocked by firewall will return `curl: (28) Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds`

Comment: in that case, I would start a `python -m http.server <port>` on the target server and then check if I can reach it for sure using the built-in `wait_for` module. Then I would start that process as a cleanup. This way I know for sure I can reach the target. I can't leave myself to trust a stderr string.