# Is it possible to write an ansible playbook that can tell me if my ec2 instance has a security group that opens a port?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, aws-security-group

I would like to write an ansible playbook that will tell me if my ec2 instances have a security group that contains a rule that allows ingress on a specified port.  I have seen answers like [Test if a server is reachable from host and has port open with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800368/test-if-a-server-is-reachable-from-host-and-has-port-open-with-ansible) where one would have this in the playbook:

```
- hosts: target.host
  tasks:
    - wait_for: host=remote.host port=8080 timeout=1
    - debug: msg=ok
```

But that tells me if something is listening on port 8080 on the remote host.  In my circumstance there will be no process listening because the service has not yet been installed.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the aws ec2 module to get Netword ACLs and apply a filter to get the one's you're after. Using tags could also be an easy method to filter the resources for your playbook. This code is untested, and you'd need to parse the response into your playbook get the information you're after. It's basically a starting point. Check this [link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/ec2_vpc_nacl_info_module.html#ansible-collections-community-aws-ec2-vpc-nacl-info-module) for further info.

```
# Retrieve Port 8080 Network ACLs
- name: Get Port 8080 NACLs
  community.aws.ec2_vpc_nacl_info:
    region: us-west-2
    filters:
      'entry.port-range.from': 8080,
      'entry.port-range.to': 8080
  register: port_8080_nacls
```